# JMeter distributed testing and command line parameters

Tags: jmeter

I have been using JMeter parameters to specify test attributes like testduration, rampup period etc for load test. I specify these parameters in shell script and it looks like this -

```
JMETER_PATH="/home/<user>/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/jmeter.sh"
${JMETER_PATH} \   
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv \
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true \
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true \    
-JCUSTOMERS_THREADS=1 \
-JGTI_THREADS=1 \
// Some more properties
```

Everything goes good here.

Now I added distributed testing and modified above script with JMeter Server related info. Hence new script looks as -

```
JMETER_PATH="/home/<user>/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/jmeter.sh"
${JMETER_PATH} \
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv \
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true \
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true \
-Jsample_variables=counter,accessToken \
-JCUSTOMERS_THREADS=1 \
-JGTI_THREADS=1 \
// Some more properties
-n \
-R     127.0.0.1:24001,127.0.0.1:24002,127.0.0.1:24003,127.0.0.1:24004,127.0.0.1:24005,127.0.0.1:24006,127.0.0.1:24007,127.0.0.1:24008,127.0.0.1:24009,12$
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 \
```

Distributed test runs well but test does not take parameters specified in script above into consideration rather it takes the default value from JMeter test plan -

[image]

Did I mess up any configuration?

Comment: Please do not post text as images. You should really be posting your first two images in code block formatting.

Comment: agreed, have changed them to code format

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `-G` instead of `-J` for properties to be sent to remote machines as well. `-J` is local only.

> -D[prop_name]=[value] - defines a java system property value.
>   -J[prop name]=[value] - defines a local JMeter property.
>   **-G[prop name]=[value] - defines a JMeter property to be sent to all remote servers.**
>   -G[propertyfile] - defines a file containing JMeter properties to be sent to all remote servers.

From [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: This is also true if you are using a properties file. The properties file is only used on the server nodes if you specify -G<prop file>. Using -p is also only local. I feel this should be the default mode for jmeter-server.

Answer (score 0):

Replace -J with -G, for more details go to link below or can see the image atached.
[If you want to run your load test in distributed mode refer to URL click here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

And search for Server Mode (1.4.5)

[image: you can refer the image]