# Cannot pass parameters to slaves with distributed JMeter setup with Maven and linux

Tags: linux, maven, jmeter, distributed, jmeter-maven-plugin

Using JMeter 2.13, Maven and Linux in all servers. Not running any tests from gui or command line, Maven is used!

Have a test plan with a lot of parameters that are set and passed from Maven execution in Jenkins to the JMeter test plan. Using "-J" in Maven to set the input parameters.
Works fine in single JMeter environment.

If I start JMeter in slaves manually first, then start the Jenkins job the test plan in the specified remote servers are started properly. But I have observed that no parameters are transferred to the remote servers. So, I can't control the test plan execution.
The temporary workaround is to hardcode some parameters in the test plan.
But this is not acceptable solution!

I've looked around a lot. Have found these pages,  [JMeter distributed testing and command line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736338/jmeter-distributed-testing-and-command-line-parameters/40178491#40178491) and [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

But I'm running from Maven, not command line, so "-G" doesn't work!

Haven't done any RMI setup, but I don't think that's the problem. 
Probably more related to how parameters should be transferred to remote servers.

With this setting in pom.xml,

```
<propertiesJMeter>
    <remote_hosts>10.71.98.54,10.71.98.82,10.71.98.81</remote_hosts>
</propertiesJMeter>
```

I did manage to get the basic slave connection to work; I see the printout of remote server IP addresses in the output/log and test plan is started and runs fine and logs seems to be okay too. 
But, problem is that parameters aren't transferred to remote servers!!

Some additional pom configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <remoteConfig>
        <startServersBeforeTests>true</startServersBeforeTests>
        <stopServersAfterTests>true</stopServersAfterTests>
    </remoteConfig>
    <propertiesUser>
        <THROUGHPUT>${throughput}</THROUGHPUT>
        <NUMBER_OF_LOOPS>${number_of_loops}</NUMBER_OF_LOOPS>
        <DURATION>${duration}</DURATION>
        <NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS>${number_of_clients}</NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS>                
    </propertiesUser>

...
```

Please, can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#adding-additional-properties-to-propertiesglobal):

> **Adding Additional Properties To propertiesGlobal**
>
> ---
>
> Global properties are properties that are sent to the remote machines. To set those properties you will need to specify each property in your **pom.xml** in the config element **propertiesGlobal** (The example below shows a property called **threads** and a property called **testIterations** being set).

```
<project>
    [...]
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jmeter</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertiesGlobal>
                            <threads>10</threads>
                            <testIterations>5</testIterations>
                        </propertiesGlobal>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    [...]
</project>
```

So it looks like you need to move these properties to `<propertiesGlobal>` from the `<propertiesUser>`

References:

- [JMeter Wiki page regarding Maven Plugin](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin)
- [JMeter Maven Plugin Wiki](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. Your first documentation link pointed to wrong page I think.
Anyway, I guess you refer to, https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#6

Quite strange that it's so hard to find from the "JMeter dist" guides you can find.

Many thanks.  :-)
The parameters works fine now.

But the remoteConfig parameters isn't working. [Jmeter remote connection throwing "Connection refused to host"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513679/jmeter-remote-connection-throwing-connection-refused-to-host)
https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Remote-Server-Configuration

But can someone confirm that the conclusion in the first link above is correct?

When I read the information in the second link I did understand it as JMeter doesn't have to be started. But it's so that "jmeter-server" has to be started, otherwize it won't be working, correct?
Guess it make sense now.